# Re-adding the Debian main repository to sources

Tags: debian, package-management

I have a friend who has installed Debian from home burned CDs. But when we try to `apt-get` new packages (eg. Audacity, Emacs) his installation doesn't recognise them ("not available from this source")

It feels like he's lost the main Debian repository from his sources. In `/etc/apt/sources.list` he only has

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates contrib main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
# A network mirror was not selected during install. The following entries
# are provided as examples, but you should amend them as appropriate
# for your mirror of choice.

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib
```

Do these include the main Debian repository? Or just the "updates"?  For example, a package calld audactiy-data is visible but not audacity itself.

If so, how can we  add the main repository again? What's its address?

Comment: Unless you intend to download and rebuild source packages, comment out all `deb-src` lines.  You can always uncomment them if/when you need to rebuild a package.  I use these aliases: `alias apt-source-on='sed -i -e "s/^#\(deb-src\)/\1/" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*'` and `alias apt-source-off='sed -i -e "s/^\(deb-src\)/#\1/" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*'` in my root shell.  add `sudo` before the `sed`s if you want to run them as a non-root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this problem so many times I 'wrote it down'

```
# tested works
# jessie updates
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.cogentco.com/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
# source list
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo apt-get update` after adding these to sources.list

Comment: super fast debian (and others) mirror

Comment: It might be "super fast" from whereever you are, but it won't be from everywhere (it looks like it's on the wrong side of the atlantic ocean for me = quite slow compared to numerous other mirrors), so please don't make that kind of statement without qualification.

Comment: He don't need to add `non free` repo  to install Emac and Audacity , It can be installed following the answer of @Stephen Harris

Comment: Thanks .. exactly what we needed. Any idea why we don't get something working as a default?

Answer (score 2):

You only have the `updates` listed.

The `base` repo you're missing is at

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
```

Comment: Any idea how / why we didn't have these main repos?

Comment: If he installed from a local CD then it might have had a 'local CD' entry that your friend removed after it started causing errors when the CD wasn't available.

Comment: The answer is in your `sources.list` = `A network mirror was not selected during install`